Undefined control sequence. \psplot
I want to plot function but I have much difficult.
Here is my code:
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[french,english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}%\iflanguage{francais},
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,mathrsfs,tikz,times,pifont,pstricks,pstricks-add,pst-func, pst-plot}
%\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}
        \begin{center}
            \begin{pspicture}(-2,-2)(4,4)
                \psset{xunit=1cm, algebraic=true}
                \psaxes{->}(0,0)(-2,-2)(4,4)
                \psplot[linecolor=red,linewidth=1.5pt]{-1}{2}{x^2-1}
            \end{pspicture}
        \end{center}
\end{document}

When I compiled it the message is : << Undefined control sequence. \psplot >>

I can't replicate the issue. Can you post the output of \listfiles and your .log?

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[french,english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}%\iflanguage{francais},
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,mathrsfs,tikz,times,pifont,pstricks,pstricks-add,pst-func, pst-plot}
%\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{pspicture}(-2,-2)(4,4)
\psset{xunit=1cm, algebraic=true}
\psaxes{->}(0,0)(-2,-2)(4,4)
\psplot[linecolor=red,linewidth=1.5pt]{-1}{2}{x^2-1}
\end{pspicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}

I would guess that if you look in the log the undefined command is \PSTrics and you are using texstudio which notoriously destroys the error messages, You need to use latex or lualatex not pdflatex with pstricks

@Gasam do not put code in comments, you can edit the question and at it to a code block, but you have already posted the document, the request was that you post the log file (which would show which tex engine you used, and show the real error message)

Sorry I don't know how to copy log files because I using phone to communicate with you and I m texting in Laptop.

no problem you can add to the question later when you are at the laptop, but I guess you were using pdflatex and teh error message was as shown in my answer.

If you use pdflatex the error message (you only show a fragment) is
! Undefined control sequence.
\c@lor@to@ps ->\PSTricks 
                         _Not_Configured_For_This_Format
l.14                 \psplot
                            [linecolor=red,linewidth=1.5pt]{-1}{2}{x^2-1}
? 

as \PSTricks is undefined. You need to use latex or lualatex (or with some restrictions, xelatex) but not pdflatex.
With lualatex your document produces

If you misreading the undefined command error message was due to your editor corrupting the message, complain to the maintainers of the editor. (This has been an open issue in texstudio for years, at least since 2016 https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/feature-requests/1068/?page=1)
The above image was produced with your code as posted but if using lualatex you should also remove
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

which sets up legacy 8-bit font encodings for pdflatex and should not be used with uniocde tex systems

Thanks. But I'm using Texstudio. There's no other methods for the Texstudio users without using lualatex?

texstudio is just the editor you are using that does not process the document at all, your latex system will be miktex or texlive and that almost certainly already includes luatex as well as pdftex, so you just need to use a menu option or configuration to run lualatex not pdflatex @Gasam

Merci infiniment pour avoir pris de votre temps pour discuter avec moi et répondre à mes lacunes en latex.

In TeXStudio use Preferences and then for build choose lualatex
